# Calculate year to date duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to calculate year to date

I try this script, it returns the good values but it's too slow

```
select 
        T.Delivery_month,
    T.[Delivery_Year],
    Sales_Organization,
    SUM(QTY) as Month_Total,

    COALESCE(
        (
            select SUM(s2.QTY) 
            FROM stg.Fact_DC_AGG s2 
            where 
                s2.Sales_Organization = T.Sales_Organization 
                and  s2.[Delivery_Year]=T.[Delivery_Year]
                AND s2.Delivery_month<= T.Delivery_month

        ),0) as YTD_Total
from  stg.Fact_DC_AGG T
group by 
    T.Delivery_month,
    T.[Delivery_Year],
    Sales_Organization
ORDER BY 
    Sales_Organization,T.[Delivery_Year],
T.Delivery_month
```

I modified it in order to optimize it, but it returns wrongs values with duplicates:

```
select 
        T.Delivery_month,
    T.[Delivery_Year],
    Sales_Organization,
    SUM(QTY) as Month_Total,

    COALESCE(
        (


        ),0) as YTD_Total
from  stg.Fact_DC_AGG T
INNER JOIN stg.Fact_DC_AGG s2 
            ON  
                s2.Sales_Organization = T.Sales_Organization 
                and  s2.[Delivery_Year]=T.[Delivery_Year]
                AND s2.Delivery_month<= T.Delivery_month
group by 
    T.Delivery_month,
    T.[Delivery_Year],
    Sales_Organization
ORDER BY 
    Sales_Organization,T.[Delivery_Year],
T.Delivery_month
```

How to optimize the query or to correct the second script ?

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2008R2? 2008 and 2008R2 have less than 2 months of support left, and neither support Window Functions to do cumulative sums. Triangular Joins can get very expensive, so if you are on 2012+ you can make a big optimisation by getting rid of it.

Comment: Optimize the query by upgrading to a supported version of SQL Server and using the cumulative sum functionality provided in 2012 and onwards.

Comment: Your query generates values for every year/month in your table. Generally speaking, no one compares YTD values for multiple years worth of data (or is it decades?). And if you do, then you expect that calculation to be somewhat slow. What is your real goal here? Are you optimizing a query for a narrow and rarely used use case? Roughly the same question asked 2 days ago with no response.

Answer (score 0):

To [optimize the performance](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2019/02/sql-server-basic-berformance-tuning-tips-and-tricks.html) of your query first you have to remove sub-query and use join instead of sub-query as well as you also need to generate an actual execution plan for your query and identify required [missing index](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2019/04/create-missing-index-from-actual-execution-plan-sql-server.html).

**NOTE:** Missing indexes might affect your SQL Server performance, that can down your SQL Server performance, So be sure to review your actual query execution plans and the identify the right index.

For more Information Please visit the following links.

1) [SQL Server Basic Performance Tuning Tips and Tricks](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2019/02/sql-server-basic-berformance-tuning-tips-and-tricks.html)

2) [Create Missing Index From the Actual Execution Plan](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2019/04/create-missing-index-from-actual-execution-plan-sql-server.html)